# Retrieve data from word file

Tags: r, import

This database for machine learning has been separated into two files,German.data is for all the values and another one is a description file, here is the link.[https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/statlog/german/?C=D;O=A](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/statlog/german/), How can I retrieve the relevant information from the word file into R?
Making it into a list which has all the attributes as its elements and within each element its factors.

Answer (score 0):

This is pulled from [GitHub](https://github.com/datascienceinc/Skater/blob/d25d4a2cbf08234f6f5e1f9a25c1ae94c3ec03a5/examples/r/deployed_model/credit_model.R):

```
 url <- "https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/statlog/german/german.data"
 col.names <- c(
 'Status of existing checking account', 'Duration in month', 'Credit history'
 , 'Purpose', 'Credit amount', 'Savings account/bonds'
 , 'Employment years', 'Installment rate in percentage of disposable income'
 , 'Personal status and sex', 'Other debtors / guarantors', 'Present residence since'
 , 'Property', 'Age in years', 'Other installment plans', 'Housing', 'Number of      existing credits at this bank'
 , 'Job', 'Number of people being liable to provide maintenance for', 'Telephone',           'Foreign worker', 'Status'
 )

 data <- read.csv(
 url
 , header=FALSE
 , sep=' '
 , col.names=col.names
 )
```